# Adding UIElement with AddLogicalChild, AddVisualChild in WPF

Tags: wpf, panel, uielement

I created a custom version of canvas by simply extending/inheriting from the Panel.

When I want to draw or render something on it, I simply create a `DrawingVisual`, draw the desired graphics and call the `AddLogicalChild(Visual)`, `AddVisualChild(Visual)` and incrementing the count of the Visuals of the Panel.

This works great when I am adding `DrawingVisual` instances, but when I try to add a `Button` here and define the dimensions (`MinHeight`, `MinWidth`), it is not displayed.

Is it possible that `UIElements` need a different logic of handling to be displayed? Basically, how can I add a `UIElement` to that extended `Panel` that would be displayed and could be manipulated with?

Answer (score 2):

**If working only with `UIElement`s**, the prefered way is to add that items to the `Children` collection.

But **if you have a mixture of `UIElement`s and `Visual`s**, I would suggest to use the methods `AddLogicalChild` / `AddVisualChild` instead of `Children`. However, that requires a little bit more work:

1. Add the item (`Visual`s as well as `UIElement`s) as logical and visual children, using `AddLogicalChild` and `AddVisualChild`.
2. Store the items somewhere (the Panel wont do it for you)
3. Overwrite `GetVisualChild` and `VisualChildrenCount` and return the number of items / the item on the passed index
4. Overwrite MeasureOverride, call `UIElement.Measure` on each `UIElement` and do all the other measure stuff that is specific for your panel
5. Overwrite ArrangeOverride, call `UIElement.Arrange` for each `UIElement` and do all the other arrange stuff that is specific for your panel

Note that `Measure` and `Arrange` have to be called **after** the UIElement has been added to the `Panel`.

Thats it. :)

Answer (score 1):

That functionality is already included. If you want to add `UIElements` to your `Panel`, simply use `.Children.Add()` - just like you do with the regular `Canvas`, `Grid` etc.

Then in your implementation, override `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride` to iterate through the children and organize them on your `Panel` surface.

Example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152(v=vs.110).aspx#Panels_custom_panel_elements

Answer (score 0):

For `UIElement`s, it's the Collection `Children` to use:

```
public void AddChild(UIElement newChild)
{
   this.Children.Add(newChild);
}
```

You should also look at the [InternalChildren](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.internalchildren.aspx) Collection which is recommanded to use in extensions of `Panel`s.

Comment: This is true but the AddLogicalChild/AddVisualChild overwrites any other visuals. In other words, as soon as I create visual with calling these two methods the Children are not drawn.

Comment: Ok I tried adding to the InternalChildren collection but visually nothing happened. There are two possible scenarios I guess: either the Visuals and Add...Child is not intended to be used with existing controls or I am missing something...